# Cannot populate UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am attempting to populate a row of a UITableView with data from an array but the 
function below is never called :

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        // Configure the cell...


        cell.textLabel?.text = arrayOfDictionaryPlaces[indexPath.row]["name"];
        println("the Cell");

        return cell
    }
```

I have set the prototype cell reusable identifier as 'Cell' and have control over the table by settings its class (viewDidLoad does get called).

Any input appreciated.

Comment: Did you set the controller where you have this code as the data source of the table view? Are you returning a non-zero value from tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:?

Comment: Is whatever class that holds this function the class that's set to the delegate of your tableview?

Answer (score 0):

The number of sections was set to zero so I changed to 1 and data is populating rows, is there reason why the number odf sections is set to 0 by default?

```
 override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }
```

Comment: I think Apple does that, just so you will pay attention to that method, and implement it correctly for your particular use. One section is default though, if you don't implement the method at all, so you can just delete the method entirely.

Comment: This is weird. Was that the only thing that you changed? numberOfSections is 1 by default which is mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: When I opened a new iOS Cocoa touch file which and assigned it a subclass if UITableViewcontroller the default section number is 0, not sure why but is confusing